# Cannot find shared libraries even -rpath is set correctly

Tags: ld, rpath

I am building a third party program which is using libraries from a directory which is not set in `/etc/ld.so.conf` - therefore I link the program with the `-rpath` option.

Running `objdump -x bin/GetHistPrices | grep -i path` to check if `-rpath` is set correctly I get the confirmation it is OK:

```
RUNPATH 
   /application/FXCM-API/GetHistPrices/bin:
   /application/FXCM-API/lib:
   /application/FXCM-API/sample_tools/lib
```

`cmake` copies all libraries into the same directory where the executable is generated [e.q. `../GetHistPrices/bin`]; therefore the 1st path is OK.

Even more, the last 2 paths point also to directories where the shared libraries are located - these `-rpath` options are added automatically by the `cmake` script.

When I try to run the program **NOT** inside the `../GetHistPrices/bin/` directory [where it is located] - e.q. I don't execute it with `./GetHistPrices` - so I get this error message:

> bin/GetHistPrices: error while loading shared libraries:
>
> ```
>   libgsexpat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

The program only gets started when I either run it from the `bin/` or `/application/FXCM-API/lib` directory because the needed library is located there.

**1)**
When I run the program with
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/application/FXCM-API/GetHistPrices/bin" bin/GetHistPrices`
then it starts. But this is what I see as well in the executable. Strange!

**2)**
Adding `/application/FXCM-API/GetHistPrices/bin` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` let start the program as well successfully.

OS is SLES 12.3 - honestly, somehow it looks to me like a bug in the system.

**My question:**

What am I doing wrong that it doesn't work even `RUNPATH` is correctly set in the executable.

Comment: I am in same state.

Answer (score 6):

May be late to answer but may be useful for others.
Some notes:

1. Consider **rpath** vs **runpath**: you can change with

> -Wl,--disable-new-dtags

2. If your lib use other libs as dependency, must set it's rpath/runpath separately (in it's make process). It's is one of differences between LD_LIBRARY_PATH an rpath/runpath.
3. You can use LD_DEBUG=libs ldd your_app/libyour_lib.so to check search paths of rpath/runpath.